# mysql insert and update dates

Tags: mysql, sql

so, I have a table named companies and I want to add 2 columns for insert and update times.

how do I do this? I dont want to add insert and update dates into my query.
this is my create statement

```sql
create table companies(
    name varchar(20),
    city char(10),
    numberofemployees int(10),
    averagesalary double

);
alter table companies add inserttime datetime, add updatedtime datetime, add id serial;
```

I need the insert query to look like this:

```sql
insert into companies values ("company","bglr",30,400.00)
```

and need output as

```
name,city,numberofemployees,averagesalary,inserttime,updatetime
company blr 30 400.00 23:00:11 23:00:11
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll *have to* change your INSERT statement since the number of values doesn't match the number of columns. Luckily, you can specify the subset of columns that correspond to the given values:

```
INSERT INTO companies(name, city, numberofemployees, averagesalary)
     VALUES ('company', 'blgr', 30, 400.00);
```

As you don't provide values for inserttime and updatetime, default values will be used for new records. Another way to insert records using default values is to put in the `DEFAULT` keyword instead of a concrete value (please refer to the documentation of [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html) for more details).

In your case the default values should be `NULL` because you didn't define anything else. To change the `DEFAULT` value for your columns, you can modify their definitions:

```
ALTER TABLE companies MODIFY COLUMN inserttime datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Having this, inserttime is set to the current time for newly inserted records. Of course, you can also use the `DEFAULT` clause in `CREATE TABLE` statements, or while adding the columns.

Next, let's have a look at the updatetime. Usually, you want this to be updated automatically to the current time. This can be achieved in MySQL by specifying an `ON UPDATE` clause for the default value (details in [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html):

```
ALTER TABLE companies MODIFY COLUMN 
            updatetime datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

From now on, updatetime will be set to the current time automatically when a new record is inserted or an existing record is updated.

More information about default values in MySQL can be found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html).